# Cannot open launch configuration on Jboss 6.1 server and neither start it

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, jboss

I'm using Eclipse 2022, and I have a Jboss EAP 6.1 server finely created, it used to work until some days ago, now as I try to start it it gives the following error

[image]

Additionally if I try to open the launch configurations of the server or the runtime environment it starts loading with the blue wheel, but it never actually opens the launch configurations.
Moreover, several operations which you can normally perform in Eclipse such as the cleaning of projects, fail with some errors which can't be found even on google. Could anyone kindly explain what is going on?
Also let me know if you need additional information such as logs or error screens.

Comment: What information is hidden behind the Details button? 2022 also saw 4 releases of Eclipse, all of which were last year. Perhaps you should update to the latest and see if this has been addressed?

Comment: Hi, this it what is hidden under the details:

An internal error occurred during: "Starting Red Hat JBoss EAP 6.1+".
org/eclipse/jdt/launching/IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants

Also I don't think the problem is the release of Eclipse, because it was working fine until few days ago, and I need additionally this very specific version of Eclipse for my project to be able to run

Comment: By the way the Eclipse realease is 2022.06

Answer (score 0):

So still now I have no idea what was going on, I guess the Eclipse IDE had simply gotten somehow corrupted.
What I did was redownloading the same version of Eclipse and re-installing  all of the plug-ins. It works fine now and the server starts.